# How to display results values of Dictionary<string, string> from a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm struggling and unable to display the `results2` of my   `Dictionary<string, string> files`

```
Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(filepath + "\\Saved Pictures\\", "*.jpg"))
{
    files.Add(file, CalculateHash(file));
}

var duplicates = files.GroupBy(item => item.Value).Where(group => group.Count() > 1);


var results2 = duplicates.Select(group => group.GroupBy(x => x.Value));
```

So far I have tried :

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> result in results2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", result.Key, result.Value);
}
```

And I'm encountering this error message:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want everything in the dictionary, why you are grouping the elements first? It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish, nor what specifically you're not able to figure out. The error message seems perfectly clear; please explain why it is it's not helpful to you, and what _exactly_ it is you want the code to do.

Comment: `GroupBy` doesn't actually produce a `Dictionary`. It produces an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...>>`. Just use `var` instead of explicitly specifying the type in the `foreach(...` and let intellisense guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. `results2` is not an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as you'd assume in the `foreach` loop, but a more complex type, an `IEnumrable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>`.

Two nested `foreach` loops will do it:

```
foreach (var grouping in results2)
{
    foreach (var pair in grouping)
    {
        // pair is a KeyValuePair<string, string>
    }
}
```

Comment: Two nested is indeed the good approach, I just didn't realize I need another nested loop , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at this code the less I understand it. What is the point of grouping already grouped values by the same property they were originally grouped by?

In plain English, I suspect you are simply trying to obtain a list of all sets of files with identical hashes. A simple way to do this is:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(filepath + "\\Saved Pictures\\", "*.jpg");

// An enumerable of enumerables of files that share the same hash
var dupes = files.GroupBy(CalculateHash).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

If you need to flatten this for display purposes, you can do:

```
// IEnumerable<(string hash, string file)>
var flattened = dupes.SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(file => (hash: grp.Key, file)));

foreach ((var hash, var file) in flattened)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {hash}, Value: {file}");
}
```